# Azure CosmosDB using Mongo Drivers: Get Count With out getting all documents based on element in sub sub document in C#.Net

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Below is my JSON structure which I'm storing in Azure MongoDB(Pasted the sample structure), I want to query using **userID** element which is present in **Plyrs** (Sub Sub document) to get list of all tournaments user has played.

1. I have tried with Aggregate() but not succeeded. Please correct me
   if I'm missing some thing, below is the code for it.
2. Tried to get using builders but not succeeded, using builders I'm able to retrieve  up to one level (sub collection , with json(pasted below) reference upto **tbls** ) is there any way that I can query on **Plyrs**(sub sub collection) .
3. Will Azure MongoDB support Aggregate() or the count with out getting the whole documents?

Please guide me **Aggregation**

```
   var count = sampleMongoDataBase.GetCollection<GameInfo>(sampleCollectionName).Aggregate()
                    .Unwind<GameInfo, TableDocumet>(t => t.Tables)
                    .Unwind<TableDocumet, PlayerDocument>(p => p.Players)
                   .Match(x => x.UserID == "3fd30fa8-f5c5-4311-8741-4032142bbb33")
                   .Group(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument { { "id", "$Plyrs._id" }, { "count", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } });
```

**Builders**

```
 mongoDataBase.GetCollection<GameInfo>(mongoCollectionName).Find(Builders<GameInfo>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Tables,t => t.TableId == 1)).Count();
```

**Error** :
Command aggregate failed: '$group' is not supported.

JSON :

`

```
{
"TnId": 651,
"QnId": "7a5de5dc-b02f-4013-9d02-ebf8430e7a56",
"samt": 10,
"tbls": [
  {
    "TblId": 1,
    "Plyrs": [
      {
        "_id": 1048995,
        "UserId": "FC381A6D717B6973-711BD743AE90E6D7",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Roman Yates",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1048996,
        "UserId": "fc3e0971-2c3c-e697-b68a-33b12a207bc2",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Neil Gaines",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1048997,
        "UserId": "FC369812-6DC04066-A133-1C10EEBA1546",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Lori Reyes",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1048998,
        "UserId": "FC2AC461-C7FAD800D3D79A2CD2680C72",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Duane Hoffman",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1048999,
        "UserId": "FC39AFCF-688C-B61A-A0DB-80EADAC832CD",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Alfredo Ware",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1049000,
        "UserId": "FC2B863D-9ACC-13C706EA-8E31917566DB",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Abigail Riddle",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "TblId": 2,
    "Plyrs": [
      {
        "_id": 1049001,
        "UserId": "FC2BCC93-DDAE-4622-8D1226BDF1181D63",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Rene Spence",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1049002,
        "UserId": "FC3D0CF42017-C3BFF460-E8DBDE3D1D77",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "TU006918",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1049003,
        "UserId": "FC2CDE495F34E557-77C8-4B10981B7758",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Marshall Lutz",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1049004,
        "UserId": "FC3EE1FDB4913FF345AE90CD14BE3607",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Roberto Burton",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1049005,
        "UserId": "FC378E3C-C2A0528F094A-7FB31BD9D278",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Summer Stephenson",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 1049006,
        "UserId": "FC431BBB-A79D45A0EAB034676C755E5A",
        "St": 3,
        "PCS": 2,
        "ConnId": null,
        "DN": "Terence Fischer",
        "RB": 2,
        "LL": 1,
        "Chips": 5000,
        "Rank": 46,
        "ExitLvl": 0,
        "TRA": 0,
        "PRI": "",
        "IsAns": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Out Put** :
For example , Count: 5

Comment: Can you please clarify if this is native MongoDB or if it's CosmosDB with MongoDB API? You didn't show any error output, so it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Hi David Makogon , it is CosmosDB with MongoDB API. I got this error when queried on Cosmos using C#.Net Command aggregate failed: '$group' is not supported.

Comment: You have to turn on the aggregation pipeline on Azure Portal (Preview Features pane) for your Cosmos DB MongoDB API account.

Comment: @user3270152 - please see my updated answer, which reflects the fact that the aggregation pipeline is now a supported feature.

Answer (score 2):

Not all MongoDB query features are surfaced in the Cosmos MongoDB API, and currently the Aggregation Pipeline is one of those features not implemented. This is why you're getting the error stating `$group` isn't supported.

> **EDIT** - As of November 2017, Aggregation Pipeline is now a supported operation with the MongoDB API of Cosmos DB. Full list of supported features is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support).

General aggregation (`sum, min, max, avg, count`) were added a while back to the DocumentDB API.

You'd have to do your own aggregation in MongoDB API, for now.

Note: `count()` is supported, so assuming you filter your data (without aggregation pipeline), you can do something like:

```
db.collection.find({...}).count()
```

Likewise, you can do a `$min` or `$max` via sorting. So for `$max`, you can do something like this to find the maximum value of `foo`:

```
db.collection.find({...},{foo:1}).sort({foo:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks David Makogon for reply, I'm trying to get using builders but I can go only up to one level, is there any way that I can get up to two levels to access player object. mongoDataBase.GetCollection<GameInfo>(mongoCollectionName).Find(Builders<GameInfo>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Tables,t => t.TableId == 1)).Count();

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation pipeline support for Cosmos DB is in private preview. Please feel free to reach out to the team or me to get it enabled for your database.

Comment: Thanks Andy Hoh,  is it available for MongoDB API also?.  Does it come with extra charge?

Comment: Yes, it is only available for the MongoDB API. It does not come with any extra charge. We can on board you to the private preview, please feel free to reach out to me (email in profile).

Comment: Thank you Andy, got this one enabled on my subscription next day itself, missed to update here. But aggregation is not working on subdocument.