# MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: '$group' is not supported.'

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Actually am using the cosmos db as my Backend i try to get count of the collection using the Linq query style.but i got this error

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed:
>   '$group' is not supported.'

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var client = new MongoClient(url);
var database = client.GetDatabase("db");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Users>("users");
var query = collection.AsQueryable<Users>().Count();
```

am getting the execption handler error in the Query line...

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed:
>   '$group' is not supported.'

Kindly help me to figure out the issue...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not *exactly* a duplicate, but the availability of `$group` has been asked several times, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44844678/272109).

Comment: Seems someone in Azure SEO has been busy. It used to be fairly simple to find references that MongoDB aggregate functions are not supported, but they appear "stangely hidden" all of a sudden. In fact, most search terms are being directed to [this "very helpful" piece of information.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-documentdb-now-supports-aggregate-functions/). Personally I have an aversion to handing over money to anyone with a marked history of deception.

Comment: Bottom line is CosmosDB is not MongoDB, despite any other claim.  If you want MongoDB functionality, then use that instead. If you think you want the  "Cosmos DB service" then you should instead be using "it's own native API" as opposed to something it claims to be "compatible" with. Which for the most part is not a true statement at all.

Comment: `var collection = database.GetCollection<Users>("users");`
`var result = collection.Find(_ => true).ToList();`
`var query = result.Count();`
this give me the exact result what i need...is this a gud way to get the result or i did anything wrongly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var collection = database.GetCollection("users"); var result = collection.Find(_ => true).ToList(); var query = result.Count(); this give me the exact result what i need...is this a gud way to get the result or i did anything wrongly

You don't need to invoke ToList() before count the number of users. Following code would be fine.

```
var query = collection.Find(_ => true).Count();
```

You can also use SQL query to get the aggregated data. Code below is for your reference.

```
SELECT value count(1) FROM c
```

To call this SQL query, we could use DocumentDb C# SDK. I tested it on my MongoDb service, worked fine on my side.

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://mymongodb.documents.azure.com"), "password");
SqlQuerySpec query = new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT value count(1) FROM c");
var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db", "users");
var documentQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionLink, query);
var count = Convert.ToInt32(documentQuery.ToList().First());
```

Comment: Any update? Have you tried it? If you have further issues about this topic, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Really thanks @Amor...i used the above method i mentioned in the comment...Because its help me to get the user collection same time the count also...